# How to load Stripe promise outside of React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, stripe-payments

I am making a Stripe promise in React, their docs say to load the promise outside of the component like so:

```
import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

// Make sure to call `loadStripe` outside of a component’s render to avoid
// recreating the `Stripe` object on every render.
const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx');

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <MyCheckoutForm />
    </Elements>
  );
};
```

My problem is that I'm getting the public key from an API and storing it in redux (we connect to several different companies). Loading it within the component is causing re-renders:

```
import React from "react";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import ExpressCheckout from "./ExpressCheckout";

const ExpressContainer = () => {
  const stripe_PK = useSelector(
    (state) => state.company.presenter.data_stripe_pk
  );
  const stripePromise = loadStripe(stripe_PK);
  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <ExpressCheckout />
    </Elements>
  );
};

export default ExpressContainer;
```

I've tried to load the redux state before the component with getState() but it comes back blank.

Comment: try adding stripe promise inside useEffect with empty array dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to defer calling `loadStripe` until you get a valid value for the PK out of your selector.

When you [provide `null`](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-provider) to the `stripe` prop of `<Elements />`, it defers initialization. You can change *one time* from a null value to a promise that resolves to a Stripe object, but then changing the `stripe` prop is not allowed.

> stripe
>
> required Stripe | null | Promise<Stripe | null>
>
> A Stripe object or a Promise resolving to a Stripe object. The easiest
> way to initialize a Stripe object is with the Stripe.js wrapper
> module. After this prop has been set, it can not be changed.
>
> You can also pass in null or a Promise resolving to null if you’re
> performing an initial server-side render or when generating a static
> site.

I've rigged up an example here with `setTimeout` to simulate a delayed load of the key and then `useEffect` to trigger calling `loadStripe`:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stripe-js-delayed-key-effect-boxmz

This is not the only way to achieve this, but it illustrates the idea.